# Plugin increase products by 25%

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I want to increase price of all my products by 25%. But i want to do this all the time even with new products.

If I insert a product with price of 100 i want that it appear with 125 there is any plugin for this?

P.S I don't want to this be visible to clients like an extra fee.

WordPress WooCommerce

Comment: There is no plugin I know do what you are asking. The this can be done with additional functions.

Comment: Sorry I will post it there thank you

Comment: @Djave All plugins questions (including WooCommerce) are off topic in WordPress StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

go to **woocommerce > products** Then select all products and press on **bulk action** then select **Edit** and press **apply**. Then the page will reload. go to the **product data** section and select **"Increase existing price by"** from **Price**. and enter the amount you need to increase by.